# How install Objective-c compiler in Freebsd?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, clang, freebsd

I installed gcc 4.2. 4.3, 4.4, I installed clang, and nothing: every time I tried to compile the gnustep ports, the message appeared: "NO Objective-c compiler on the system"

What I have to do to install an Objective-c compiler in Freebsd 9.0?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm, you shouldn't had to manually install any compilers. All needed Obj-C stuff should've been installed by gnustep port you wanted to install. Maybe this have something to do with removing Obj-C runtime from FreeBSD base in 9.0

Comment: I used the "make install clean" aproached. Maybe exist other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, there is a port [lang/objc](http://freshports.org/lang/objc), which installs an independent (not even GNU) implementation.

If you prefer GNU's family of compilers, pick [lang/gcc47](http://freshports.org/lang/gcc47) -- this will install objective-C (as well as FORTRAN and even GNU's Java). If you don't wish to build from ports, you can install a pre-built package:

```
pkg_add -r gcc47
```

But the commenters are right in that GNUstep port(s) should take care of this for you. The port devel/gnustep itself is currently unmaintained, unfortunately, but you are, likely, trying to install something else (windowmaker, perhaps?). Contact the maintainer of the port, that you actually care for... Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can have working Objective-C 2.0 compiler on FreeBSD.

- [Cocoa on FreeBSD](http://brilliantobjc.blogspot.kr/2012/12/cocoa-on-freebsd.html)
- [I made a convenient script](https://github.com/eonil/bootstrap)